# problem with filtering in a referenceproperty dropdown - Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have the following problem. I have a contact class that different 
users can tag with their own topics:

```
class Contact(db.Model): 
    contact_date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True) 
    remarks = db.TextProperty() 
    topic = db.ReferenceProperty(Topic) 
class Topic(db.Model): 
    topic = db.StringProperty(required=True) 
    description = db.TextProperty() 
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='topic_set') 
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return '%s' % (self.topic)
```

In the form for this i want to only show the Topics for a certain user

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, user_filter,  *args, **kwargs): 
        self.base_fields['topic'].queryset = Topic.all().filter('owner 
= ', user_filter) 
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I then call the ContactForm from the view as follows:

form = ContactForm(user_filter = request.user.key())

This all works as expected. However when I submit the form I get:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: Unsupported type for property  : 
<class 'django.http.QueryDict'>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this some problem with appengine django 
implementation? 
Peter

Comment: Can you show us the full exception, and the code it occurs on? It doesn't look like it's anything to do with the code you've shown us.

Comment: Nick, I have solved it. I had the following:
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.user.key())
added data = request.POST
Thanks you helped me looking in other places

Answer (score 0):

A Contact can have one Topic and one Topic only. As you explained:

> I have a contact class that different users can tag with their own topics

I would move the `ReferenceProperty` to the Topic class:

```
class Topic(db.Model): 
    contact = db.ReferenceProperty(Contact)
```

Now one Contact can have multiple Topics.

Your exception comes from assigning a property with a Request Query Dictionary. This probably comes from declaring `user_filter` as an argument, but using it as a keywords argument.
It should be:

```
form = ContactForm(request.user.key())
```

But as stated above, first you should revise your models.